# Spring Integration JpaInboundChannelAdapterSpec Update method

Tags: spring-integration

Why isn't there an equivalent `updateSQL()` (as in `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`) for `JpaInboundChannelAdapterSpec`? Please confirm if manual persist through `handle()` should be called to update polled records as NOT to pick the same again?

**UPDATE**
[image]

```
    @Bean
    public JpaInboundChannelAdapterSpec dBJpaInboundSpec() {

        return Jpa.inboundAdapter(entityManagerFactory)
                    .entityClass(XYZ.class)
                    .jpaQuery("SELECT a FROM XYZ a WHERE a.status is null")
                    // trick to update the polled record
                    .deleteAfterPoll(true)
                    .maxResults(maxMessagesPerPoll);
    }

    @Bean
    public PollerSpec dBPollerSpec() {

        return Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofMinutes(pollInterval))
                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)
                    .transactional()
                    .advice(loggingAdvice);
    }

2022-10-21 20:05:57,559 [scheduling-2              ] ERROR o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler - b46f904d98859f6f org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=[REMOVED_FOR_OBVIOUS_REASONS], headers={REMOVED_FOR_OBVIOUS_REASONS}]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:427)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.con
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not implement like you'd expect just because JPA is not just about DB, but persistent entity state in the memory. So, if you just did an update on the entity, then downstream logic is going to deal with that updated data - not an original you have polled from persistent layer before.

Yes, it is better to do such an update already after processing in this case manually.

I also always recommend a trick with an `org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete` where you indeed can specify an `UPDATE` query. That `JpaInboundChannelAdapterSpec` has this option then:

```
/**
 * If set to 'true', the retrieved objects are deleted from the database upon
 * being polled. May not work in all situations, e.g. for Native SQL Queries.
 * @param deleteAfterPoll Defaults to 'false'.
 * @return the spec
 */
public JpaInboundChannelAdapterSpec deleteAfterPoll(boolean deleteAfterPoll) {
```

Comment: Thanks, `SQLDelete` did the trick. However, any error thrown in the `SQLDelete` did not stop the flow further. Is that can be controlled?

Comment: Not sure why? The logic there is like this `checkDelete(payload);` and then `return payload;` in the `poll(@Nullable final Message<?> requestMessage)`. Can you, please, share a stack trace to determine how effect you and why the fetched entity is propagated downstream?

Comment: Please check the UPDATE in original message

Comment: Doesn't look like that stacktrace shows that entity is passed down to the flow. Perhaps it confused you that it starts a new polling cycle: kinda your app doesn't break with that error.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm certain the entity was passed down the flow. I have confirmed this by keeping a single record in DB. Does it anyway relate to `transactional()` setting on the poller, which is required to run the delete (update) SQL?

Comment: No, that's not possible. See that line `AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:427)`. It is a catch of the exception from the `return this.pollingTask.call();`. Since it does not return because of exception, it cannot pass data downstream. You might have something else in your configuration which reads that data so other way.

Comment: Apologies, just an observation. When debugging was on, still the entity got passed downstream, attached screenshot for your reference. Does the `deleteAfterPoll()` run on a separate thread?

Comment: That's just impossible: if you catch an error there, then nothing is returned from that call. You are observing something else. Everything is done in the same thread. Since you can debug it here, please, consider to set a break point into the `JpaExecutor.poll(@Nullable final Message<?> requestMessage)` method on the `checkDelete(payload);` line. And see how it is going from here.

Comment: Please take a look at this sample integration project where I'm able to simulate the issue https://github.com/syedyusufh/entity-delete-after-poll.git

Comment: Cool ! I will look into that a bit later. Thank you for such a great sample!

Comment: Confirmed. By default we rely on the TX. So, you got that exception when the process is fully done on the TX commit attempt. Add `.flushAfterDelete(true)` to the `Jpa.inboundAdapter()` configuration and you'll fail immediately when `this.entityManager.flush()` is called just after `delete()`.